# Unir PDF con firma digital con Merger

Tags: pdf

Hola amigos buenas noches tengo un caso estoy trabajando un sistema de tramite documentario con firma digital y como se adjuntan varios PDFs al expediente, al final necesito unirlos para imprimirlo en un solo archivo y donde uso merger en donde me une normal el pdf pero las firmas se pierden del pdf, he visto esta pagina https://www.ilovepdf.com/es/unir_pdf que une normal con todo firma aunque el pdf se pierde la validez de la firma, que eso no me interesa porque solo necesito para imprimirlo, habrá alguna librería o para hacer algo parecido a esa pagina.

```
include 'PDFMerger.php';

use PDFMerger\PDFMerger;
$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('file1.pdf');
$pdf->addPDF('file3.pdf');
$pdf->merge('download','merged.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola ya resolví mi problemita con las librerías shellcommand y pdftk
para la unión de pdf firmados obviamente el valor de pdf unido pierde el valor pero la idea es unir solamente.

Primero se debe de instalar PDFtk - The PDF Toolkit https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Segundo descargar libreria para ejecutar comandos de PDFtk
https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-shellcommand

Lista de comandos de PDFtk
https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/

EJEMPLO:

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use mikehaertl\shellcommand\Command;
$command = new Command("pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf cat output pdfunido.pdf");
if ($command->execute()) {
    echo $command->getOutput();

} else {
    echo $command->getError();
    $exitCode = $command->getExitCode();
}
```